# Trie data structure timecomplexity

Tags: data-structures, trie

Assuming that the strings to be stored in a Trie are 'n' number of characters long. What would be the execution time for insert(), search() and remove() ?

I have looked on the internet, but I didn't really get a clear answer. Can anyone shortly mention please the time complexity for these three operations.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Algorithms) Wikipedia article, both insertion and searching run within a worst-case runtime bound of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the argument to insert or search. To my understanding, removal of a string is not a typical feature of a trie data structure.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the search and insertion time complexity is O(n), but for deletion I am not sure how it work.

Comment: @user9419320 Deleting a node also is O(n), with n being the length of the item to delete. The simple (not fastest) way is to find the item and then work backwards, deleting leaf nodes.